# Workflow Rule not working and unable to auto launch a flow

Tags: visual-flows, workflowrule

I created a workflow rule with a field update. Which worked I needed to add another field update to the existing workflow rule that would remove a check mark. The workflow still fires the first field update to change the status but it will not fire the remove check mark.

Case - Replacement Order Emails

Evaluation Criteria

- created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria

Rule Criteria

- ((Email Message: Subject CONTAINS Replacement order) OR (Case: Subject CONTAINS REPLACEMENT ORDER:)) AND ((Email Message: From Address EQUALS lnotifier@AcuityBrands.com) OR (Case: Web Email EQUALS lnotifier@acuitybrands.com)) AND (Case: Case Record Type EQUALS Customer Care)

Workflow Actions

- Field Update

  - **Name** Junk or Informational Email
  - **Unique Name** Junk_or_Informational
  - **Description** if a status is changed to informational or junk, that it will mark the status as that and will also clear the new email checkbox.
  - **Object** - Case
  - **Field to Update** Case: New Email
  - **Field Data Type** Checkbox
  - **Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change** Checked
  - **New Field Value** False
- Field update

  - **Name** Informational Email
  - **Unique Name** Informational_Email
  - **Description**
  - **Object** Case
  - **Field to Update** Case: Status
  - **Field Data Type** Picklist
  - **Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change** Checked
  - **New Field Value** Informational

I then created a flow with the same criteria and the flow works when I run it manually how do i make this flow work without users having to press a button. I need the flow to run in the background like the workflow does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you will want to avoid using workflow rules and instead use Process Builder or Flow Builder. For what you want to do here, you will need to create a process in Process Builder to kick off your flow (although you may find that you can create the whole thing as a process and avoid the flow altogether).

1. If you already have a process on the Case object, you'll want to add this as another criterion and actions in your existing process. (Try to keep it to one process per object, for maintainability and control over the order of execution.) Otherwise, create a new process and choose Case as the object, and start the process when a record is created or edited.
2. Set your criteria the same as you did on your workflow rule.
3. For your action type, you could choose Flows and launch your flow - but you can probably also just do an Update Records action type and assign your values.

The [Lightning Flow module on Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/business_process_automation) has some good content about when to use which tool.